# Powershell - creating hashtables from large text files and searching

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm working with a hashtable which I've built using a list of 3.5 million IP addresses stored in CSV format, and I am trying to search through this table using wildcards.

The CSV is MaxMind's list of IPs, which I convert to Hashtable using the following code

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\temp\iptest.csv") | ForEach-Object { $data= $_.split(','); $ht = @{"geoname_id"="$($data[1])";"registered_country_geoname_id"="$($data[2])"}
$name = $($data[0])
$mainIPHhash.add($name, $ht)}
```

The code just pulls out the CIDR and it's corresponding City/Country code.
This works well, and builds the table in a little over two minutes, but the issue I am now facing is searching this hashtable for wild card entries.

If I search for a complete CIDR, the search happens in milliseconds

```
$mainIPHhash.item("1.0.0.0/24")

Measure command reports - TotalSeconds : 0.0001542
```

But if I need to do a wildcard search, it has to loop through the hashtable looking for my like values, which takes a long time!

```
$testingIP = "1.0.*"
$mainIPHhash.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.key -like $testingIP }

Measure command reports - TotalSeconds : 33.3016279
```

Is there a better way for searching wildcard entries in Hashtables?

Cheers

Edit:

Using a regex search, I can get it down to 19 seconds. But still woefully slow

```
$findsStr = "^$(($testingIP2).split('.')[0])" +"\."+ "$(($testingIP2).split('.')[1])" +"\."

$mainIPHhash.GetEnumerator() | foreach {if($_.Key -match $findsStr){#Dostuff }}
```

The above takes the first two octets of the IP address, and uses regex to find them in the hashtable.

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 19
Milliseconds      : 733
Ticks             : 197339339
TotalDays         : 0.000228402012731481
TotalHours        : 0.00548164830555556
TotalMinutes      : 0.328898898333333
TotalSeconds      : 19.7339339
TotalMilliseconds : 19733.9339
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the list of IPs and do either `-like` or `-match` for a list. Either should be faster than a `Where-Object` clause

```
$mainIPhash.Values -like '1.0.*'

$mainIPhash.Values -match '^1\.0\.'
```

Comment: You sir, are a legend. That worked perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: Which was faster? I have a really large list with many duplicates.

Comment: They are pretty on par! Out put from measure-command for the first - TotalMilliseconds : 0.1165. The second - TotalMilliseconds : 0.1237

Answer (score 0):

Other solution may be, use group-object :

```
$contentcsv=import-csv "C:\temp\iptest.csv" -Header Name, geoname_id, registered_country_geoname_id |Group Name
$contentcsv | where Name -like '1.0.*'
```

Comment: Thanks! The only issue is import-csv with a file this large is that is eats up a huge amount of resources.

Comment: ah ok, i understand :)